# Comparing Calculated Date Columns

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I have multiple calculated date columns and am using them to calculate some dollar amounts. These amounts are changing on every save, regardless of whether the day changes. Is this because the field is calculating purely based upon date/time...but just displaying the date? Is there anyway to do just date?

Thanks.

Comment: All Item (singular!) Calculated Formulas are re-calculated on every Item (singular) save/update. All Items (plural) Formulas are re-calculated on every Formula change

Comment: Add your formulas to your post

Comment: I'm aware of when, but do they go to the second? Coming with formulas.

Comment: `=DATEDIF([Launch Date],[End Date],"d")+1` `=[End Date]-UploadDate`  `=[Net Budget]-[Spend to Date]` `=[Remaining Budget]/[Days Left]` `=Modified-1` Launch Date, End Date, UploadDate and Days Left are all "Date Only" columns. The other ones are money columns.

Comment: Your dates that are Date Only technically have a time of midnight. Modified has a time down to seconds. So if you're calculating an amount from `Modified-1` it will include seconds